# Why must passengers in Blue Origin flights be able to climb seven flights of stairs at the launch tower in less than 90 seconds?

Tags: blue-origin, tourism, astronaut-recruitment

https://amp.theguardian.com/science/2021/jun/12/jeff-bezos-space-auction-28m-spare-seat-blue-origin states:

> Passengers, the company has said, must be between 5ft and 6ft 4in tall, weighing 110-223lb. They must also be able to climb seven flights of stairs at the launch tower **in less than 90 seconds** and sit strapped in the vehicle for as long as 90 minutes without access to a lavatory.

Why must passengers in Blue Origin flights be able to climb seven flights of stairs at the launch tower in less than 90 seconds? Why this time limit on the stair climbing?

Comment: At a guess, so they can get back down the stairs in case of an emergency?

Comment: In order to [keep Elon Musk out](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/05/09/elon-musk-shares-personal-diet-and-exercise-routine-joe-rogan-podcast.html).

Comment: https://twitter.com/orcaspace1/status/1403776677549903872?s=19

Comment: If you climb stairs to evacuate launch tower in an emergency, it is good to be fast.

Comment: If you're climbing stairs to evacuate, you're going the wrong way

Comment: It's probably a "minimum fitness level" thing. Spaceflight is dangerous and BO doesn't want to deal with extracting someone who can't walk properly from the capsule in case of an emergency. I mean, seven flights is probably only 80 something steps, and if you can't do those in less than 90 seconds, you probably shouldn't be strapping yourself to the tip of a rocket in the first place.

Comment: Climbing seven flights of stairs in 90 seconds is also probably something you can test and train  yourself for in your home city surreptitiously, without submitting yourself to tests at Blue Origin's facilities and risking the embarrassment of failing.

Answer (score 4):

These are simply physical health requirements.  Do not want someone in your spacecraft having a heart attack or requiring other medical attention: this is one part of reducing chance of that.  Being able to sit for 90 minutes without need to urinate or defecate is also a health requirement and a much more directly practical one.

Comment: Got a source on this?

Comment: This does not make much sense. If they fear passengers having heart attacks they would use proper methods for screening them.